# Numeric vector: entries that are within epsilon far from each other

Tags: r, vector

Consider a positive numeric vector like `vec` as follows:

```
vec <- c(0.453, 0.864, 0.340, 0.941, 0.612, 0.899, 0.910, 0.238, 0.184, 0.803)
```

Suppose we want to find the elements that are within epsilon far from each other. A possible way is:

```
epsilon <- 0.1
cmb <- combn( length(vec), 2 )
diff <- vec[ cmb[1,] ] - vec[ cmb[2,] ]
cmb [ ,abs(diff) <= epsilon ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]    2    2    2    2    4    4    6    6    8
#[2,]    4    6    7   10    6    7    7   10    9
```

A well-known question: Can we do better?

Answer (score 1):

You don't define "better". Here is an alternative:

```
epsilon <- 0.1
d <- as.matrix(dist(vec))
which(d < epsilon & lower.tri(d), arr.ind = TRUE)
#   row col
#4    4   2
#6    6   2
#7    7   2
#10  10   2
#6    6   4
#7    7   4
#7    7   6
#10  10   6
#9    9   8
```

Performance could be further optimized for large input vectors by avoiding the coercion to a dense matrix:

```
d <- dist(vec)
n <- attr(d, "Size")
i <- which(d < epsilon)
rown <- (n-1):1
cols <- findInterval(i, c(0,cumsum(rown)), left.open = TRUE)
rows <- i - cumsum(rown)[cols - 1] + (1:n)[cols]
rbind(cols, rows)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#cols    2    2    2    2    4    4    6    6    8
#rows    4    6    7   10    6    7    7   10    9
```